# Rstudio toolbar flipped to right-to-left after update

Tags: r, rstudio

I just updated my Rstudio following a prompt, to "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for Windows. This somehow resulted in the top toolbar getting flipped and is not presented right-to-left (see screenshot).
[image]
Has anyone encountered this, and know why this is happening and how to fix it?

I tried to find a setting for it in the Global Options but no luck there.